Looking for an Excel formula to counts dates excluding weekends
I'm trying to write a formula to count public holidays between two given dates from a holiday list. Meanwhile, I need to exclude a holiday date if it is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday).
My trial formula:
=COUNTIFS(Holiday_Range,">="&Date1,Holiday_Range,"<="&Date2)

But that formula counts all listed dates even if it is Saturday or Sunday.
I would appreciate any support in that.
My Holiday List

I'm expecting 5 days out of the below list. But the result is 8 !!



Occasion
Day
Date




New Year's Day
Sat
1-Jan-2022


Fasching
Mon
28-Feb-2022


International Women's Day
Tue
8-Mar-2022


Good Friday
Fri
15-Apr-2022


Easter Monday
Mon
18-Apr-2022


Labour Day
Sun
1-May-2022


Mother's Day
Sun
8-May-2022


Ascension Day
Thu
26-May-2022




With COUNTIFS() you could try: =COUNTIFS(Holiday_Range,">="&Date1,Holiday_Range,"<="&Date2,B2:B9,"<>Sat",B2:B9,"<>Sun")

You could also use: =NETWORKDAYS(MIN(Date),MAX(Date)) - NETWORKDAYS(MIN(Date),MAX(Date),Date) where Date refers to your list of holiday dates.

Here is one possible way using SUMPRODUCT() function:


• Formula used in cell G2
=SUMPRODUCT((Holiday_Range>=E2)*(Holiday_Range<=F2)*(WEEKDAY(Holiday_Range,2)<6))


Where:
• Cell E2 is the Start Date or Date1
• Cell F2 is the End Date or Date2 --> Both Date1 and Date2 are assumptions as its not declared in the post.
• While Holiday_Range refers to C2:C9

If using MS365 then use SUM() function with LET()
=LET(α, Holiday_Range, SUM((α>=E2)*(α<=F2)*(WEEKDAY(α,2)<6)))


NOTE You might need to change cell reference or ranges as per your suit.

